# What the heck is this pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I removed the drywall in my utility room to inspect the plumbing and found a mystery pipe. I have no idea what it's for or what it is. Can anyone help me identify this thing's current or former purpose? Here is a picture showing other things in the vicinity. FYI the floor you see is a concrete slab so there's no getting under it to see where it goes.

[image]

Comment: Natural gas or propane (disconnected.) Or old water pipe - hard to say for sure.

Comment: Anything anybody suggests will be a guess at best. Mine is an abandoned water line that was replaced with the new (at the time)copper line, because of the proximity of the existing water supply. If it is galvanized (which may be rusty pipe) pipe, or lead, the chance is better. If it is cast iron pipe, there is no chance it is a water supply.

Comment: It's possible that it's part of a heating system and went to a radiator.

Comment: Cold have been an old version of hot.  Hot pipes clog faster, leak faster, have shorter lives.